# I have this error when i want to build my solution

Tags: android, xamarin

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
Error       The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'support-annotations.jar' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)
   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Dental_IT.Android
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is most likely linked to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70591/build-error-resolvelibraryprojectimport-task-failed-unexpectedly-access-denied) post on the Xamarin forums, and [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=49067) bugzilla entry. Without a reproducible sample, all I can advise you try is:

Updating Xamarin for Visual Studio, Xamarin.Android, and Xamarin.iOS to the latest stable versions
Cleaning and rebuilding
Deleting all of the bin and obj folders from your project directories
Restarting Visual Studio/your PC
Failing all of that, there's not likely to be anyone who can help you without a reproducible sample and potentially your Xamarin logs.

Comment: It works now when I restart my VS; clean and rebuild my VS solution. Thanks!